Mitmproxy doesn't capture the traffic I need
Here is my problem, the thing I'm trying to do is to capture the market activity from a game (I need the api key), but mitmproxy only captures player settings and a config, is there a way to get more information?
Already tried to root my device, still won't work.

In which mode do you use Mitmproxy? On what platform is the game running you want to capture?

Well, I have connection between my pc and android emulator (bluestacks). I use the regular mode by connecting emulator with ProxyCap to my pc's ip-adress, also have the certificate installed.

I also get those kind of errors, while capturing some TLS packages - Client TLS handshake failed. The client may not trust the proxy's certificate for cdp.cloud.unity3d.com (OpenSSL Error([('SSL routines', '', 'tlsv1 alert access denied')]))
